# How do I initialize a new database-path defined in stack.yaml

Tags: haskell-stack

The sample [Docker configuration](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/docker_integration/#configuration) section of `stack.yaml` gives:

```
  # Location of database used to track image usage, which `stack docker cleanup`
  # uses to determine which images should be kept.  On shared systems, it may
  # be useful to override this in the global configuration file so that
  # all users share a single database.
  database-path: "~/.stack/docker.db"
```

However when I put this in the `stack.yaml` for a new project and `stack setup` I get:

```
Aeson exception:
Error in $.docker['database-path']: failed to parse field 'docker': failed to parse field 'database-path': InvalidAbsFile "~/.stack/docker.db"
See http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/
```

This is the [only reference I could find](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=database-path&type=) to `database-path`, without digging in to the code.

Is `database-path` required?

If so: How do I initialize a `.db` file (to mitigate `InvalidAbsFile "~/.stack/docker.db"`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a matter of initialization of the database.  The problem is that it does not expand the `~`, so you need to use `/home/dukedave/.stack/docker.db`